# Re-wiring a bathroom

Tags: electrical, bathroom

So I have a bathroom that I am going to remove the old wiring, add a new breaker and pull new wire to from the breaker panel the bathroom. I want to install an exhaust fan and a vanity light on the same switch with a new duplex outlet next to the switch. The outlet should have power independent of the switch. Wires will run through the attic down to the vanity and down to the Outlet and switch. Would some one help me with a drawing of how the wires should run.

Thanks,

[image: bathroom]

Comment: Do you mean one switch to control both light and fan (no independent control) or one switch *location* to separately control them?

Comment: One switch to control both the light and the fan. Light on, Fan on. Light off, Fan off.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/27475/33) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, would be to wire it up like this.

[image]
<sup>*Grounding conductors excluded for simplicity. Make sure the grounding conductors are connected properly.*</sup>

- Install a 20 ampere breaker in the panel.
- Run 12/2 with ground from the panel to the switch box.
- Run 12/2 with ground from the switch box to the fan, and the light.
- Connect the black ungrounded conductor to the two switches and GFCI receptacle, using pigtails.
- Connect the white grounded conductor to the GFCI receptacle, and whites from the cables running to the fan and light.
- Connect the black from the fan cable to one switch.
- Connect the black from the light cable to the other switch.
- Connect all grounding conductors.

Answer (score -1):

12/2 romx from panel 2 switch box, then 12/2 to light (black as switch leg) & out to fan.

Comment: Please edit this so it's more clear what you're suggesting. Complete sentences or bullet points would be helpful.